# getting data from certian website via python

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get the Chinese Yuan exchange rate to USD from the Bank of China website, however I'm lost in trying to get the data out of the website, here is my code:

```py
from lxml import etree
import requests

s = "https://www.boc.cn/sourcedb/whpj/enindex_1619.html"
page = requests.get(s)
tree = etree.HTML(page.text)
element = tree.xpath('./body/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[26]/td')
content = etree.tostring(element[0])
```

the `element` variable is where the USD line in that page after I inspected the page
when I run the program I get this message:

> File "d:\Python\tebotCopy.py", line 8, in 
> content = etree.tostring(element[0]) IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try different XPath to get row with USD:

```py
import requests
from lxml import etree

s = "https://www.boc.cn/sourcedb/whpj/enindex_1619.html"
page = requests.get(s)
tree = etree.HTML(page.text)

element = tree.xpath('//table[@bgcolor="#EAEAEA"]/tr[27]/td')
for td in element:
    print(td.text, end=" ")
print()
```

Prints:

```
USD 641.51 636.29 644.23 644.23 646.12 2021.10.14 07:23:51
```